# Updating highcharts using ajax for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, highcharts

I've set up some charts using highcharts, populating it's series column using the brilliant 'gon' gem. Now, i'm trying to update it's results using ajax.

Here's what my setup looks like:

**user_controller:**

```
gon.segmentedData = ActiveRecord query here..
```

**application.js**

```
var weekly_options = {  //Some standard highcharts options here


                    series: gon.segmentedData  
                };
```

This renders the chart perfectly. I want to ajaxify this chart using the following action

**view:**

```
<div class = deposit>
<%= form_tag transact_path, :remote => true, :validate => true, :method => :post do %>
.
.
.
 <%= submit_tag "Deposit", :id => 'deposit_button', :class => 'round', :disable_with => 'Please wait..' %>
```

To get updated data to the chart, i re-populate series data in the transaction_controller's create action

**transaction_controller**

```
def create
 gon.segmentedData = ..
end
```

**create.js :**

```
   var options = //here i pass all the options again

    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

My problem is that i'm unable to get an updated set of options to create.js through the transaction_controller. The same chart gets rendered again.

Would highly appreciate if someone could critique this approach for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems fetching updated data from my controllers to populate my highcharts data. Instead of using gon, which kept returning stale data, I switched to json. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

Use lazy-high-chart to save your time!

https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts

e.g.
In controller,

```
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "area"
f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
end
```

In view,

```
<%= high_chart("my_id", @h) %>
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising!